# "IDW10503: Cannot determine the cloud Instance." when trying to get access token

Tags: asp.net, .net, oauth

I'm trying to integrate Microsoft and Google oauth into my Blazor server app.
Here's the configuration code in startup:

```cs
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie()
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = "...";
                    options.ClientSecret = "...";
                    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.Events.OnCreatingTicket += new CustomClaimsHelper().AddCustomClaims;
                    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.Scope.Add(PeopleServiceService.ScopeConstants.UserinfoProfile);
                })
                .AddMicrosoftAccount(MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind(Constants.AzureAd, options);
                    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-aad";
                    options.Events.OnCreatingTicket += new CustomClaimsHelper().AddCustomClaims;
                    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.Scope.Add("User.Read");
                });
            services.AddTokenAcquisition();
```

My expectation of the oauth workflow is like this:

1. The user click on log in button, say it's a Microsoft user and he/she is redirected to Microsoft login screen.
2. After the login is done by Microsoft, a authorization code is sent to my app from. Then an access token is fetched. The access token is stored to the cookie. This is all automatically done by the Microsoft oauth middleware, which is configured in the `AddMicrosoftAccount` method.
3. I should be able to fetch the access token and use it to call the Microsoft Graph APIs.

But when I try to acquire the access token to read the Micrsoft user's profile using `_tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string []{"User.Read"});`, I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: IDW10503: Cannot determine the cloud Instance. The provided authentication scheme was 'Cookies'. Microsoft.Identity.Web inferred 'Cookies' as the authentication scheme. Available authentication schemes are 'Cookies,Google,Microsoft'. See https://aka.ms/id-web/authSchemes

Is my understanding of the oauth workflow in asp.net core wrong? What should I do to resolve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Calling ITokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync throws IDW10503 error](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1828#issuecomment-1197520248)

I suspect the correct way to make the call above would be:

```
var token = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes: scopes, authenticationScheme: authenticationScheme);
```

i.e. specify the authenticationScheme.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also read that post. But that is indeed how I called it in my code... Anyway, I have worked around the issue by calling the API manually with HttpClient. Will accept this answer if there's no better answer showing up.